# Error when binding an .AAR in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

i'm trying to bind the core library: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

I downloaded the .AAR file from Maven Central and did everything in this tutorial Binding an .AAR, but when i'm building the Binding Library i'm getting this errors:

```
'CardExpandableListAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'BaseExpandableListAdapter.GetGroup(int)'
Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'CardWithList.LinearListAdapter' is less accessible than method 'CardWithList.GetLinearListAdapter()'
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'CardWithList.LinearListAdapter' is less accessible than method 'CardWithList.SetLinearListAdapter(CardWithList.LinearListAdapter)'
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'CardWithList.LinearListAdapter' is less accessible than property 'LinearListView.Adapter'
'CardView' does not implement interface member 'ICardViewWrapper.SetExpanded(bool)'
'CardView' does not implement interface member 'ICardViewWrapper.SetForceReplaceInnerLayout(bool)'
'CardView' does not implement interface member 'ICardViewWrapper.SetLongClickable(bool)'
'CardView' does not implement interface member 'ICardViewWrapper.SetOnExpandListAnimatorListener(ICardViewWrapperOnExpandListAnimatorListener)'
'CardView' does not implement interface member 'ICardViewWrapper.SetRecycle(bool)'
```

It looks like the binding generator has some bugs, is there any fix for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From Xamarin's page,

> When you are generating Java Bindings, there are several common error scenarios that you may run into.

Here is the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/) to possible errors you might run into and how to resolve them.

[Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/#Problem_Class_does_not_implement_interface_method) for how to fix "Interface does not implement method"

Inconsistent accessibility issue can be resolved by changing the visibility accordingly. Here is an example of how to modify visibility

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.somepackage']/class[@name='SomeClass']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```